# JSTL sessionScope attribute

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jstl

I need to retrieve a session attribute in a .jspx file and the following does not work:

In the controller I set the attribute as follows:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("error", 1);
```

Then try to retrieve the attribute in the .jspx file:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.error eq 1}">
    <p>Retrieved</p>
</c:if>
```

I do not get the "Retrieved" message.
What am I doing wrong?

If I just use request.SetAtribute and don't use the sessionScope, everything works as intended. Why?

Comment: `<c:if test="${error eq '1'}">`

Comment: this won't compile because of ' '

Comment: what is the compilation error message ?